# Django. Creating a field that is a copy of an existing field in a related model.

Tags: python, django

I would like to have a field, that is simply a copy of another field.

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bar')
    copy = foo.bool # i would want this to be equal to bar.foo.bool
```

Comment: Do you actually want Bar to store the copied value in its db table, or can it just get it from Foo?

Comment: Just get it from Foo. This is a minimal example, but in reality I need it to link to an existing imagefield and I dont' want to store the image twice (since I have about 20k high-res images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a property:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bar')

    @property
    def copy(self):
        return self.foo.bool
```

Note, even for your real use case this is pretty pointless, you can always access the image field via the FK.

Comment: This seems like what  I need. I'm gonna try it out.

Comment: "even for your real use case this is pretty pointless, you can always access the image field via the FK" => technically right, but this breaks encapsulation by exposing implementation (cf law of demeter) NB :  whether this is an issue is another debate, of course  !-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in this in models, even if possible it is not advised. Further, you can use `django.db.models.signals.post_save` [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) to store the same results when a field or model gets saved or updated. Another way is changing values in views.py.